# For loop with timed iterations - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, iteration

I want to implement a for loop such that for each iteration, it will wait exactly one second before going to the next.

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i <=3; i++) {
   //...do something
   //...wait one second
}
```

Comment: Will that freeze the main thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `dispatch_after` to avoid blocking the main thread while waiting:

```
- (void)loopAndWait:(NSUInteger)currentIndex maxIndex:(NSUInteger)maxIndex {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // do stuff
        NSUInteger nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;
        if (nextIndex <= maxIndex) {
            [self loopAndWait:nextIndex maxIndex:maxIndex];
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Arguably, this would probably be better if it took a block argument and called that block where you have the `//do stuff` comment.  That certainly makes it more reusable.

Comment: @nhgrif undoubtedly so, I just didn't want to pack too many new (for the OP) concepts into one answer ;)